# jQuery slickQuiz plugin: support multiple quizes on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Please see comment under question first.

**I apologize to those that have read this question so far (10 views).  I'm still not sure of the syntax to pass in the quiz configuration but she apparently allows it.**

I'm trying to make a small change so the [slickQuiz plugin](https://github.com/jewlofthelotus/SlickQuiz) supports multiple quizes on the same page, which the [author 3 years suggested it probably can do.](https://github.com/jewlofthelotus/SlickQuiz/issues/36)   However it's loading in the same quiz questions and it seems due to the defining of quizJSON in slickQuiz-config.js file:

```js
// Setup your quiz text and questions here

var quizJSON = {
    "info": {
        "name":    "Test Your Knowledge!!",
        "main":    "<p>Think you're smart enough to be on Jeopardy?
   ... continues on ...
  }
};
```

and the following line in slickQuiz.js, apparently allowing no variability on the quizJSON configuration loaded in:

```
    // Set via json option or quizJSON variable (see slickQuiz-config.js)
    var quizValues = (plugin.config.json ? plugin.config.json : typeof quizJSON != 'undefined' ? quizJSON : null);
```

I'm quite new to Javascript and am not sure how I could pass something in to set which quiz configuration (questions/answers) file is used for quizValues .  Note the plugin includes a tiny master.js file, where it appears I can set a different id for each quiz:

```
 // master.js file -- originally just defined #slickQuiz

 $(function () {
  $('#slickQuiz').slickQuiz();
 });

 $(function () {
   $('#slickQuiz2').slickQuiz();
 });
```

But how do I pass a parameter into slickQuiz() that I can use inside slickQuiz.js? This is probably trivial, but the way the function is invoked and its options are confusing to me new to JS.

Note here is how the slickQuiz id gets used in the plugin's example html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">

        <title>SlickQuiz Demo</title>

        <link href="css/reset.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/slickQuiz.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/master.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body id="slickQuiz">
        <h1 class="quizName"><!-- where the quiz name goes --></h1>

        <div class="quizArea">
            <div class="quizHeader">
                <!-- where the quiz main copy goes -->

                <a class="button startQuiz" href="#">Get Started!</a>
            </div>

            <!-- where the quiz gets built -->
        </div>

        <div class="quizResults">
            <h3 class="quizScore">You Scored: <span><!-- where the quiz score goes --></span></h3>

            <h3 class="quizLevel"><strong>Ranking:</strong> <span><!-- where the quiz ranking level goes --></span></h3>

            <div class="quizResultsCopy">
                <!-- where the quiz result copy goes -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/slickQuiz-config.js"></script>
        <script src="js/slickQuiz.js"></script>
        <script src="js/master.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is most of the slickQuiz.js file (only allowed to copy in so much, rest at link above):

```js
/*!
 * SlickQuiz jQuery Plugin

(function($){
    $.slickQuiz = function(element, options) {
        var plugin   = this,
            $element = $(element),
            _element = '#' + $element.attr('id'),

            defaults = {
                checkAnswerText:  'Check My Answer!',
                nextQuestionText: 'Next &raquo;',
                backButtonText: '',
                completeQuizText: '',
                tryAgainText: '',
                questionCountText: 'Question %current of %total',
                preventUnansweredText: 'You must select at least one answer.',
                questionTemplateText:  '%count. %text',
                scoreTemplateText: '%score / %total',
                nameTemplateText:  '<span>Quiz: </span>%name',
                skipStartButton: false,
                numberOfQuestions: null,
                randomSortQuestions: false,
                randomSortAnswers: false,
                preventUnanswered: false,
                disableScore: false,
                disableRanking: false,
                scoreAsPercentage: false,
                perQuestionResponseMessaging: true,
                perQuestionResponseAnswers: false,
                completionResponseMessaging: false,
                displayQuestionCount: true,   // Deprecate?
                displayQuestionNumber: true,  // Deprecate?
                animationCallbacks: { // only for the methods that have jQuery animations offering callback
                    setupQuiz: function () {},
                    startQuiz: function () {},
                    resetQuiz: function () {},
                    checkAnswer: function () {},
                    nextQuestion: function () {},
                    backToQuestion: function () {},
                    completeQuiz: function () {}
                },
                events: {
                    onStartQuiz: function (options) {},
                    onCompleteQuiz: function (options) {}  // reserved: options.questionCount, options.score
                }
            },

            // Class Name Strings (Used for building quiz and for selectors)
            questionCountClass     = 'questionCount',
            questionGroupClass     = 'questions',
            questionClass          = 'question',
            answersClass           = 'answers',
            responsesClass         = 'responses',
            completeClass          = 'complete',
            correctClass           = 'correctResponse',
            incorrectClass         = 'incorrectResponse',
            correctResponseClass   = 'correct',
            incorrectResponseClass = 'incorrect',
            checkAnswerClass       = 'checkAnswer',
            nextQuestionClass      = 'nextQuestion',
            lastQuestionClass      = 'lastQuestion',
            backToQuestionClass    = 'backToQuestion',
            tryAgainClass          = 'tryAgain',

            // Sub-Quiz / Sub-Question Class Selectors
            _questionCount         = '.' + questionCountClass,
            _questions             = '.' + questionGroupClass,
            _question              = '.' + questionClass,
            _answers               = '.' + answersClass,
            _answer                = '.' + answersClass + ' li',
            _responses             = '.' + responsesClass,
            _response              = '.' + responsesClass + ' li',
            _correct               = '.' + correctClass,
            _correctResponse       = '.' + correctResponseClass,
            _incorrectResponse     = '.' + incorrectResponseClass,
            _checkAnswerBtn        = '.' + checkAnswerClass,
            _nextQuestionBtn       = '.' + nextQuestionClass,
            _prevQuestionBtn       = '.' + backToQuestionClass,
            _tryAgainBtn           = '.' + tryAgainClass,

            // Top Level Quiz Element Class Selectors
            _quizStarter           = _element + ' .startQuiz',
            _quizName              = _element + ' .quizName',
            _quizArea              = _element + ' .quizArea',
            _quizResults           = _element + ' .quizResults',
            _quizResultsCopy       = _element + ' .quizResultsCopy',
            _quizHeader            = _element + ' .quizHeader',
            _quizScore             = _element + ' .quizScore',
            _quizLevel             = _element + ' .quizLevel',

            // Top Level Quiz Element Objects
            $quizStarter           = $(_quizStarter),
            $quizName              = $(_quizName),
            $quizArea              = $(_quizArea),
            $quizResults           = $(_quizResults),
            $quizResultsCopy       = $(_quizResultsCopy),
            $quizHeader            = $(_quizHeader),
            $quizScore             = $(_quizScore),
            $quizLevel             = $(_quizLevel)
        ;


        // Reassign user-submitted deprecated options
        var depMsg = '';

        if (options && typeof options.disableNext != 'undefined') {
            if (typeof options.preventUnanswered == 'undefined') {
                options.preventUnanswered = options.disableNext;
            }
            depMsg += 'The \'disableNext\' option has been deprecated, please use \'preventUnanswered\' in it\'s place.\n\n';
        }

        if (options && typeof options.disableResponseMessaging != 'undefined') {
            if (typeof options.preventUnanswered == 'undefined') {
                options.perQuestionResponseMessaging = options.disableResponseMessaging;
            }
            depMsg += 'The \'disableResponseMessaging\' option has been deprecated, please use' +
                      ' \'perQuestionResponseMessaging\' and \'completionResponseMessaging\' in it\'s place.\n\n';
        }

        if (options && typeof options.randomSort != 'undefined') {
            if (typeof options.randomSortQuestions == 'undefined') {
                options.randomSortQuestions = options.randomSort;
            }
            if (typeof options.randomSortAnswers == 'undefined') {
                options.randomSortAnswers = options.randomSort;
            }
            depMsg += 'The \'randomSort\' option has been deprecated, please use' +
                      ' \'randomSortQuestions\' and \'randomSortAnswers\' in it\'s place.\n\n';
        }

        if (depMsg !== '') {
            if (typeof console != 'undefined') {
                console.warn(depMsg);
            } else {
                alert(depMsg);
            }
        }
        // End of deprecation reassignment


        plugin.config = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // Set via json option or quizJSON variable (see slickQuiz-config.js)
        var quizValues = (plugin.config.json ? plugin.config.json : typeof quizJSON != 'undefined' ? quizJSON : null);

        // Get questions, possibly sorted randomly
        var questions = plugin.config.randomSortQuestions ?
                        quizValues.questions.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }) :
                        quizValues.questions;
   
        // Count the number of questions
        var questionCount = questions.length;

        // Select X number of questions to load if options is set
        if (plugin.config.numberOfQuestions && questionCount >= plugin.config.numberOfQuestions) {
            questions = questions.slice(0, plugin.config.numberOfQuestions);
            questionCount = questions.length;
        }

        // some special private/internal methods
        var internal = {method: {
            // get a key whose notches are "resolved jQ deferred" objects; one per notch on the key
            // think of the key as a house key with notches on it
            getKey: function (notches) { // returns [], notches >= 1
                var key = [];
                for (i=0; i<notches; i++) key[i] = $.Deferred ();
                return key;
            },

            // put the key in the door, if all the notches pass then you can turn the key and "go"
            turnKeyAndGo: function (key, go) { // key = [], go = function ()
                // when all the notches of the key are accepted (resolved) then the key turns and the engine (callback/go) starts
                $.when.apply (null, key). then (function () {
                    go ();
                });
            },

            // get one jQ
            getKeyNotch: function (key, notch) { // notch >= 1, key = []
                // key has several notches, numbered as 1, 2, 3, ... (no zero notch)
                // we resolve and return the "jQ deferred" object at specified notch
                return function () {
                    key[notch-1].resolve (); // it is ASSUMED that you initiated the key with enough notches
                };
            }
        }};

        plugin.method = {
            // Sets up the questions and answers based on above array
            setupQuiz: function(options) { // use 'options' object to pass args
                var key, keyNotch, kN;
                key = internal.method.getKey (3); // how many notches == how many jQ animations you will run
                keyNotch = internal.method.getKeyNotch; // a function that returns a jQ animation callback function
                kN = keyNotch; // you specify the notch, you get a callback function for your animation

                $quizName.hide().html(plugin.config.nameTemplateText
                    .replace('%name', quizValues.info.name) ).fadeIn(1000, kN(key,1));
                $quizHeader.hide().prepend($('<div class="quizDescription">' + quizValues.info.main + '</div>')).fadeIn(1000, kN(key,2));
                $quizResultsCopy.append(quizValues.info.results);

                // add retry button to results view, if enabled
                if (plugin.config.tryAgainText && plugin.config.tryAgainText !== '') {
                    $quizResultsCopy.append('<p><a class="button ' + tryAgainClass + '" href="#">' + plugin.config.tryAgainText + '</a></p>');
                }

                // Setup questions
                var quiz  = $('<ol class="' + questionGroupClass + '"></ol>'),
                    count = 1;

                // Loop through questions object
                for (i in questions) {
                    if (questions.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        var question = questions[i];

                        var questionHTML = $('<li class="' + questionClass +'" id="question' + (count - 1) + '"></li>');

                        if (plugin.config.displayQuestionCount) {
                            questionHTML.append('<div class="' + questionCountClass + '">' +
                                plugin.config.questionCountText
                                    .replace('%current', '<span class="current">' + count + '</span>')
                                    .replace('%total', '<span class="total">' +
                                        questionCount + '</span>') + '</div>');
                        }

                        var formatQuestion = '';
                        if (plugin.config.displayQuestionNumber) {
                            formatQuestion = plugin.config.questionTemplateText
                                .replace('%count', count).replace('%text', question.q);
                        } else {
                            formatQuestion = question.q;
                        }
                        questionHTML.append('<h3>' + formatQuestion + '</h3>');

                        // Count the number of true values
                        var truths = 0;
                        for (i in question.a) {
                            if (question.a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                                answer = question.a[i];
                                if (answer.correct) {
                                    truths++;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Now let's append the answers with checkboxes or radios depending on truth count
                        var answerHTML = $('<ul class="' + answersClass + '"></ul>');

                        // Get the answers
                        var answers = plugin.config.randomSortAnswers ?
                            question.a.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }) :
                            question.a;

                        // prepare a name for the answer inputs based on the question
                        var selectAny     = question.select_any ? question.select_any : false,
                            forceCheckbox = question.force_checkbox ? question.force_checkbox : false,
                            checkbox      = (truths > 1 && !selectAny) || forceCheckbox,
                            inputName     = $element.attr('id') + '_question' + (count - 1),
                            inputType     = checkbox ? 'checkbox' : 'radio';

                        if( count == quizValues.questions.length ) {
                            nextQuestionClass = nextQuestionClass + ' ' + lastQuestionClass;
                        }

                        for (i in answers) {
                            if (answers.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                                answer   = answers[i],
                                optionId = inputName + '_' + i.toString();

                                // If question has >1 true answers and is not a select any, use checkboxes; otherwise, radios
                                var input = '<input id="' + optionId + '" name="' + inputName +
                                            '" type="' + inputType + '" /> ';

                                var optionLabel = '<label for="' + optionId + '">' + answer.option + '</label>';

                                var answerContent = $('<li></li>')
                                    .append(input)
                                    .append(optionLabel);
                                answerHTML.append(answerContent);
                            }
                        }

                        // Append answers to question
                        questionHTML.append(answerHTML);

                        // If response messaging is NOT disabled, add it
                        if (plugin.config.perQuestionResponseMessaging || plugin.config.completionResponseMessaging) {
                            // Now let's append the correct / incorrect response messages
                            var responseHTML = $('<ul class="' + responsesClass + '"></ul>');
                            responseHTML.append('<li class="' + correctResponseClass + '">' + question.correct + '</li>');
                            responseHTML.append('<li class="' + incorrectResponseClass + '">' + question.incorrect + '</li>');

                            // Append responses to question
                            questionHTML.append(responseHTML);
                        }

                        // Appends check answer / back / next question buttons
                        if (plugin.config.backButtonText && plugin.config.backButtonText !== '') {
                            questionHTML.append('<a href="#" class="button ' + backToQuestionClass + '">' + plugin.config.backButtonText + '</a>');
                        }

                        var nextText = plugin.config.nextQuestionText;
                        if (plugin.config.completeQuizText && count == questionCount) {
                            nextText = plugin.config.completeQuizText;
                        }

                        // If we're not showing responses per question, show next question button and make it check the answer too
                        if (!plugin.config.perQuestionResponseMessaging) {
                            questionHTML.append('<a href="#" class="button ' + nextQuestionClass + ' ' + checkAnswerClass + '">' + nextText + '</a>');
                        } else {
                            questionHTML.append('<a href="#" class="button ' + nextQuestionClass + '">' + nextText + '</a>');
                            questionHTML.append('<a href="#" class="button ' + checkAnswerClass + '">' + plugin.config.checkAnswerText + '</a>');
                        }

                        // Append question & answers to quiz
                        quiz.append(questionHTML);

                        count++;
                    }
                }

                // Add the quiz content to the page
                $quizArea.append(quiz);

                // Toggle the start button OR start the quiz if start button is disabled
                if (plugin.config.skipStartButton || $quizStarter.length == 0) {
                    $quizStarter.hide();
                    plugin.method.startQuiz.apply (this, [{callback: plugin.config.animationCallbacks.startQuiz}]); // TODO: determine why 'this' is being passed as arg to startQuiz method
                    kN(key,3).apply (null, []);
                } else {
                    $quizStarter.fadeIn(500, kN(key,3)); // 3d notch on key must be on both sides of if/else, otherwise key won't turn
                }

                internal.method.turnKeyAndGo (key, options && options.callback ? options.callback : function () {});
            },

            // Starts the quiz (hides start button and displays first question)
            startQuiz: function(options) {
                var key, keyNotch, kN;
                key = internal.method.getKey (1); // how many notches == how many jQ animations you will run
                keyNotch = internal.method.getKeyNotch; // a function that returns a jQ animation callback function
                kN = keyNotch; // you specify the notch, you get a callback function for your animation

                function start(options) {
                    var firstQuestion = $(_element + ' ' + _questions + ' li').first();
                    if (firstQuestion.length) {
                        firstQuestion.fadeIn(500, function () {
                            if (options && options.callback) options.callback ();
                        });
                    }
                }

                if (plugin.config.skipStartButton || $quizStarter.length == 0) {
                    start({callback: kN(key,1)});
                } else {
                    $quizStarter.fadeOut(300, function(){
                        start({callback: kN(key,1)}); // 1st notch on key must be on both sides of if/else, otherwise key won't turn
                    });
                }

                internal.method.turnKeyAndGo (key, options && options.callback ? options.callback : function () {});

                if (plugin.config.events &&
                        plugin.config.events.onStartQuiz) {
                    plugin.config.events.onStartQuiz.apply (null, []);
                }
            },

   *** had to delete code because stackoverflow limits what I can put into a question, 
   here is the end of the slickQuiz file found at the link above: 
 

        plugin.init();
    };

    $.fn.slickQuiz = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (undefined === $(this).data('slickQuiz')) {
                var plugin = new $.slickQuiz(this, options);
                $(this).data('slickQuiz', plugin);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I mistakenly took a different version than her latest:  in her latest version (different git repository, https://github.com/jewlofthelotus/SlickQuiz) she says under Available Options one can pass in a json  object, I'm just not sure how yet.  If you can suggest how I'd be grateful.

Comment: It's not very helpful, I agree. Try placing the JSON in the same folder as your page is at and then use it's absolute path ex.`http://www.example.com/path/to/cfg.json`